# What is the meaning of HIGH CORRELATION in pandas profiling?

Tags: pandas, pandas-profiling

I'm trying to use `pandas profiling` on titanic dateset.
Under the overview section there are some features with caption "`HIGH CORRELATION`"

- I know what is the meaning of correlation, but the caption doesn't tell which feature is correlated to this feature ?
- So what is the meaning of "`HIGH CORRELATION`" in the pandas profiling doc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on the `Warnings` tab it will tell what other feature the features are correlated with as seen in this [example](https://pandas-profiling.github.io/pandas-profiling/examples/master/census/census_report.html). Can see the same thing in the [example](https://pandas-profiling.github.io/pandas-profiling/examples/master/titanic/titanic_report.html) with the actual titanic data.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the threshold to determine what is considered `HIGH CORRELATION`. For example (using the current latest version `3.1.0` of `pandas_profiling`),

```
profile = ProfileReport(df, 
                        missing_diagrams=None, 
                        interactions=None,
                        correlations={"pearson": {"calculate": True, "threshold": 0.8},
                                      "spearman": {"calculate": False},
                                      "kendall": {"calculate": False},
                                      "phi_k": {"calculate": False},
                                      "cramers": {"calculate": False}},
                        explorative=True)
profile
```